# Give read permission to Particular site instead of Files.Read.All in Microsoft Graph Api permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

In the Azure AD app registration, I was trying to grant File read permission to the App that I created, however it only has Fies.Read.All which gives read permission to all sites which is way to broad

[image]

Is there a way to give File Read permission on a site level?

Answer (score 1):

Not using Graph -- using the older SharePoint Add-in model, you can scope your rights to a specific library or site.

Answer (score 0):

API permission in App Registrations didn't provide option to set permission to a specific site collection.

You can use SharePoint Add in and set permission in AppManifest.xml, it will only set the permission for the site collection where the add in hosted:

[image]

Reference:

[Add-in permissions in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/add-in-permissions-in-sharepoint)